# Error with probit by hand "cannot coerce type closure with vector of type double

Tags: r, function

I am trying to code a probit by hand using R and I'm getting the error 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

```
{

    probitll<-function( X, Y){ 
     Y<-as.matrix(Y)
     X<-as.matrix(X)
     K<-ncol(X)
     b<-as.matrix(par[1:K])
     R<-pnorm(X%*%b)
     sum(Y*log(R)+(1-Y)*log(1-R))
    }
    {grad<-function( X, Y){
      + X<-as.matrix(X)
      + Y<-as.matrix(Y)
      + K<-ncol(X)
      + b<-as.matrix(par(1:K))
      + R<-pnorm(X%*%b)
      + apply(R*X, 2, sum)
    }

    resultprobit<-optim(beta, probitll, gr=grad,  Y=Y, X=X, method="BFGS", control=list(fnscale=-1), hessian=TRUE)

Error in optim(probitll, gr = grad, Y = Y, X = X, method = "BFGS", control = list(fnscale = -1),  : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
```

Comment: It comes from `as.matrix(par(1:K))` I suppose? `par` is a function. And please edit the question with the error *right after* the code line that gave it.

Comment: OK I just did. It comes at the end right afte the <optim> comand. I tryed removing <par> into the function but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I didn't explain myself well. When `optim` calls `grad` the error is thrown. What is `par` doing exactly? Try just `b<- matrix(1:K, ncol = 1)`.

Comment: ok now i'm getting this error :

[Error in optim(startvalues, probitll, gr = grad, Y = Ydoc, X = Xbiais,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite]